# Use SVN instead of CVS on SourceForge

Tags: svn, cvs, sourceforge

I've just setup a new project on SourceForge and the admins set it up with CVS as the SCM, however, I want to use SVN. There is NO code in this project yet - empty directory.

How do I change this project from using `CVS` to `SVN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under the options.